# Seven-sided dice from five-sided dice with finite rolls

Tags: probability, dice, uniform-distribution

I have a 5-sided dice, and I want to use it to simulate a 7-sided dice.
Is there a way to do this with a *finite* number of rolls?

Comment: Unless you can discard at least one side of the five-sided die in one of the rolls, this is not possible: given $n$ rolls, the number of possible outcomes equals $5^n$. Since $7 \nmid 5^n$, this cannot result in a uniform distribution for 7 possible outcomes.

Comment: Nitpicking: neither a $5$-sided nor a $7$-sided dice with equal probability for each side does exist. The only polyhedrons suitable for games have four, six, eight, twelve, or twenty sides.

Comment: What if we use non-uniform mass distribution?
And the use of dice is just meant to save me from terminology I'm not sure of, regarding discrete uniform distributions.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe:  Actually, you can make a fair $n$-sided die for arbitrary $n>1$.  One approach:  a long prism with regular $n$-gon cross section and spherical caps on each end.  (And a "coin" for $n=2$...). 
 There are other ways too....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it with a *bounded* number of rolls. This is because if you know you will stop after at most $k$ rolls, the probability of each outcome or combination of outcomes is a multiple of $\big(\frac15\big)^k$, but $\frac17$ isn't.

If you're ok with the number of rolls being unbounded, but finite with probability $1$, you can do this. For example, rolling two dice gives $25$ possible outcomes. Assign three each to the numbers $1$ to $7$, and if one of the other four outcomes comes up, reroll. (More efficient schemes exist.)

The average number of times you roll two dice with this is $\frac{25}{21}$, since the probability of stopping is $\frac{21}{25}$ at each attempt (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)). So the average number of dice you need is $\frac{50}{21}$.

Comment: And what about a way to simulate it with a number of draws without upper bound but whose average is finite ?

Comment: Yes, this has finite average, will edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: sorry it was clear

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clarification of bounded vs. finite.