# Can a 7-sided die be simulated by rolling two 5-sided dice, discarding and re-rolling when their total exceeds $7$?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, dice

Regarding simulating a 7-sided die roll with two 5-sided dice: 
I understand the question ["Seven-sided dice from five-sided dice with finite rolls"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478153/756822) and [this answer to it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2478165/756822). But,

> Why can't you just add $\operatorname{rand}(5)+\operatorname{rand}(5)$, then ***discard and re-roll*** if the result is greater than $7$?

I understand that the worst-case runtime is $O(\infty)$, but the answer linked above also has $O(\infty)$ worst-case.

Note: This is my first stack-exchange question, so please feel free to give feedback on question-asking style.

Comment: Your proposal is to sum the results of two tosses of $d5$, discarding any result $>7$?  But then how would you get $1$ as a possible outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add two $5$ rolls and then subtract off the sum to get $1$ as the minimum roll because there will be an *unequal* number of ways to get different results.  For instance, if you sum two $5$-die rolls and then subtract $1$, there is only *one* way to get a final $1$ (roll 1 and roll 1).  But there are *two* ways to get a final $2$ (roll 1 and roll 2 *OR* roll 2 and roll 1).  It is twice as likely you'll get a final $2$ than a final $1$ by that approach.

If you allow (possibly infinite) re-rolls (as you apparently do), there are many fair methods to make a $7$-sided die from a $5$-sided one.

Here is one of the simplest, conceptually:

***Method 1***:  Roll the $5$-sided die $7$ times in sequence and record which roll came out with the highest value (if first roll, then 1; if second roll then 2, ...).  If there are ties for the maximum, then start over.

This is not very efficient, though.

***Method 2***:  A *slightly* more efficient method is like the above, but if there is a tie for maximum value, then look for the sequence position where you got the *minimum* value, and use that as the index to the final value.  If you get ties for *both* the maximum *and* the minimum, then start over.

You can do *slightly* better than this, with...

***Method 3***:  As in Method 2, but if you get a tie on the maximum *and* on the minimum, look for the position that has the value 1 less than the maximum on the rolls (and it is not the minimum).  If there are several of those, then re-start.

And you can construct ever-more complicated and slightly more efficient methods...

***Method 4***:  Find the sequence location of a $5$.  If there are none or more than $1$, then find the sequence location of a $4$.  If there are none or more than $1$, the find the sequence location of a $3$....  If all this fails, start over.

Comment: The explanation definitely helps me understand why method I proposed doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My pleasure....

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to roll the $5$-side die twice and interpret the result as a number $N$ between $1$ and $25$. Then discard the result and the repeat the experiment if $N$ is  greater than $7$?

Comment: @RobArthan: It might matter that you can't ever roll a "7" that way. (That's assuming you  mean the result to be "$(d5)\times(d5)$".)

Comment: @Blue: No. Where did you get that assumption from? As I said, you can interpret the outcomes of two rolls as a uniformly distributed number between $1$ and $25$ (e.g., as $N = 5((d_1-1)+(d_2-1) +1$ where $d_1$ is the outcome of the first roll and $d_2$ is the outcome of the second.

Comment: @RobArthan: *"Where did you get that assumption from?"* Well, when I think of two "5"s and an outcome of $25$, multiplication tends to spring to mind. Sorry. :)

Comment: @Blue: I meant to say "uniformly distributed between 1 and 25" in my first comment. Apologies for any confusion. (In this kind of context, when I think of two outcomes with 5 possibilities, the cartesian product of the sets of possibilities comes to mind.)

Comment: @RobArthan You can reduce the number of trials required on average by rerolling if $N > 7 \cdot 3 = 21$ and otherwise reducing modulo $7$ to obtain a value.

Comment: @TravisWillse: sure. I wasn't claiming an optimal solution, just a simpler one than any of the ones in the answer above (of which there are now four, all looking at first glance much more complicated than my proposal with or without your optimisation, which I think is similar to the solution proposed in Ross Millikan's answer below).

Answer (score 3):

The sums of two random numbers in $\{1,\ldots,5\}$ are not evenly distributed in $\{1,\ldots,7\}$.  In fact there is no way to get
a sum of $1$, and $3$ is twice as likely as $2$.

EDIT: Since $5^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$, here's a fairly efficient way.  Take $6$ rolls of the $5$-sided die, subtract $1$ from each, and interpret the result as a base-$5$ number from $0$ to $5^6-1$.  If the result is $5^6-1$ (i.e. the $6$ rolls were $(5,5,5,5,5,5)$, do over: otherwise take the number mod $7$, add $1$ and there is your result.

Comment: (Beat me to it....)

Comment: I understand that answer. To clarify, what is the math behind this answer? That would help me understand why I can't shift the set by subtracting 1 and still rejecting all rolls with (sum-1) > 7.

Comment: @KS: Entering `2d5-1` into [anydice.com](https://anydice.com), you can see that there's a 12% chance of a re-roll. The in-range values are decidedly unequal in their likelihood ("1" has a 4% chance, while "5" has a 20% chance), so this is not a good simulation of `1d7`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and pointing me to that website.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a red and green five sided die, there are $25$ results from rolling the two of them.  You can assign three results to each of the $7$ numbers, which leaves a $\frac 4{25}=16\%$ chance of a reroll.  For example, $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)$ become $1,\ (2,2),(2,3),(3,2)$ become $2$ and so on.  If you throw away the information of which roll you had to reroll, you expect to roll about $1.19$ times to get a result.  You can do a bit better if you keep track of which of the four rerolls you got because you can pair one or two of the potential rerolls on the second round with each of the four from the first and get seven more throws that you resolve.  That takes more keeping track of than I think is worthwhile.